# NodeJs Kill and then start process

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, process, electron

I trying to make restart of my electron application. 
So on windows i have a bat file with next content:
`taskkill /IM %1 /f
 start /high %2`

And i start this bat file from node js using spawn:

```
var processName = process.execPath.split('\\');
    ls = spawn(file, [processName[processName.length - 1], process.execPath],{detached:true});
    ls.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });

    ls.on('exit', function(code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
    });
```

But after killing process the new one not start.

So how can i kill process of my electron program and then start?
Btw i start my program like exe.

Comment: The module electron-connect has a simple process manager that lets you start/restart the main process -- [take a look at how they do it here](https://github.com/Quramy/electron-connect/blob/master/lib/server.js)